# Finite Element Analysis formula

Tags: discrete-mathematics, numerical-methods

[image]
[image]

Dear all, above is quoted from a comprehensive video at [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9cUtiasAh_Y&ab_channel=SamR), may I know if the temperature value at the **center of the square**  I get from the above iteration formula will be the same if I use a 4 times 4 mesh size versus 16 times 16 mesh size, does the mesh size matter ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with finite elements... You should edit the title.

Comment: One could more easily make a case for this having something to do with finite differences...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in general yes the temperature values obtained will depend on the mesh size. It might not seem like it at first glance because the discretization of the second derivative matrix $A$ you get *is* independent of the mesh size, but the problem is that you are actually solving a matrix equation $Ax = b$ where $b$ is a vector of values obtained from the given boundary conditions. But the boundary conditions are evaluated only at the nodes, so in general these will be different depending on the mesh size (whenever they are nonconstant). Therefore the solution $x = A^{-1}b$ must in general depend on the mesh size too, except in the case that the boundary conditions are constant, but in this case the solution is constant too so of course we shouldn't expect the values to depend on the mesh size.

I also want to point out that this is a finite difference method, *not* a finite element method.